# Strange behaviour on Scale or Resizing Custom View

Tags: android

I have a Custom View representing a domino Stone. I want the User to be able to Grab/drag a Domino from his "Hand" (LinearLayout at the Bottom) to the middle. So the DominoView has to be sized from a small (hand state) to a bigger (2.5 times bigger) state to fit the middle position.

But I am quite confused handling this resizing.

So I start playing around (see attached Screens) and had a view problems.

my First approach was to build the Big Version and scaling it with

```
dominoView.setScaleX(0.5f)
dominoView.setScaleY(0.5f)
```

To Fit the LinearLayout in the Hand. But I had Problems handling the borders between the Views, think of a false or missing implementation in onMeasure.
[image: Look at the bottom]

The second approach is to change the Views LayoutParameter's height/width but in this approach the background and the textView (gravity="center") aren't redrawed, due to `requestLayout()`

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)dominoView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 200;
            params.width = 100;
            dominoView.setLayoutParams(params);
            dominoView.requestLayout();
            dominoView.invalidate();
            dominoView.forceLayout();
```

[image: Before Sizing]
[image: After Sizing]

So could anybody give me a hint to get this resizing working?

View:

```
public class DominoView extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String TAG = DominoView.class.getSimpleName();



    // SETTINGS
    private static final int ROTATION_DURATION = 750;

    private State state = State.HAND;

    private boolean rotating = false;
    private boolean draging = false;
    private TextView[] tvNummbers = new TextView[2];
    private int[] numbers = new int[2];

    private float mtvOriginSize , mOriginHeight, mOriginWidth;

    public interface IRotation {
        public void onRotationEnd();
    }

    public DominoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);

    }

    public DominoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DominoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.domino, this, true);
        tvNummbers[0] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.domino_tv1);
        tvNummbers[1] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.domino_tv2);


        fillViews(numbers);
    }


    public void setValues(int[] numbers) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setValues " + numbers[0] + "|" + numbers[1]);
        this.numbers = numbers;
        fillViews(numbers);
    }

    private void fillViews(int[] numbers){
        try {
            tvNummbers[0].setText("" + numbers[0]);
            tvNummbers[1].setText("" + numbers[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public TextView[] getTextViews(){
        return tvNummbers;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/domino"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:background="@drawable/domino_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/domino_tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/text_domino"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3px"
        android:background="@color/black_default" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/domino_tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_domino"
        android:textSize="45sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for reading this guys!